# Rstudio: plot lat/long to US map, from data file, with time series, issues

Tags: r, rstudio

Update to the update on color: I have Postal_Code in the data file. So I would need the help in banding the Postal_Code and mark the dot/bubble with color accordingly to the number of times a lat/long dot/bubble is plotted and is also in the high or low banded range of a postal_code.

For example, the banding range of Postal_Code to color:

1 - 20      White 
21 - 40     Blue
41 - 60     Green
61 - 80     Yellow
81 - 100    Purple
101 - 120   Orange
120 - beyond    Red

--

Update: Progress: I have plotted teh lat/long to a US map. Here is the string of code I used to accomplish:

```
# After data extraction and convert to .csv, load file to Rstudio

map <- get_map(location = 'united states', 
zoom = 4, source = 'stamen') ggmap(map, fullpage = TRUE);

# call libs for maps and plotting already installed 
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)

#load us map data
all_states <- map_data("state")

#plot all states with ggplot
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_polygon( data=all_states, 
aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group),colour="white", fill="grey10" )
p;

# plot data points (lat/long) to US map
p + geom_point(data=latlonguvdec14, 
aes(y=Latitude, x=Longitude), color="red");
```

I have successfully accomplished the main task, get the lat/long plotted to the US map. Now I need help in making this a time series or a time lapse type of display, sounds kinda like animation. And I'm open to ideas on how to display.

I want the oldest lat/long data to display first, and then populate that way till the end, say from 12/01/2014 to 12/31/2014.

Then I want to use color and size of dot/bubble to change, as the data is being plotted over time to the map. Say if the same dot/bubble get hit twice, change to a color, if again then another color, and up-tick it in size a little each time. Some sort of variation on this would be very helpful.

Imagine these are phone calls coming into a call center, some will be repeat callers.

--

I have installed Rstudio 0.98.1103. I have installed the plug-ins "ggmap" and "ggplot2". I have created a .csv file that has a header and has lat/long data, and date/time, the file layout looks like this:

start_dt,   start_tm, latitude, longitude
12/31/2014,  150432,    41.75,     -83.63

And I have been able to display a Google Map, via this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
#load us map data
all_states <- map_data("state")
#plot all states with ggplot
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_polygon( data=all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group =      group),colour="white", fill="grey10" )
```

p

The issue: I'm trying to plot the data points of the lat/long data to the US map, and can't seem to get any plot command to work. I've been all over Google/Youtube trying to find examples and not everyone demos ggplot2. Once I get the lat/long data points to plot with color and size, etc, then I want to be able to run this as a time series, I think that is the correct verbiage..., where it reads the date or date and time, and then plots in oldest to newest order, each lat/long data point.

Any and all help for this newbie to R is greatly appreciated.

Thank You